# Have a issue with the const , let , var and reference

Tags: javascript, algorithm, global-variables

I am doing some JavaScript coding practice, and I wanna copy the Graph

```
/**
 * // Definition for a Node.
 * function Node(val, neighbors) {
 *    this.val = val === undefined ? 0 : val;
 *    this.neighbors = neighbors === undefined ? [] : neighbors;
 * };
 */

/**
 * @param {Node} node
 * @return {Node}
 */
var cloneGraph = function(node) {
    
    visited = {};
    return recursion(node);
    
    function recursion(node){
        
        if (!node) return null;
        if (visited[node.val]) return visited[node.val];
        
        // clone node and clone edge
        // **I forgot the let, var, const variable declaration here**
        root = new Node(node.val);
        visited[root.val] = root;
        
        if (!node.neighbors) return root;
        for (let i = 0; i < node.neighbors.length; i++) {
            root.neighbors.push(recursion(node.neighbors[i]));
        }
        return root;
    }
};
```

Here is my code. I forgot to add the variable declaration `const`, `let`, `var` when initialize the new Node. However, seems like the reference is not correct here.

Error : `You must return the copy of the given node as a reference to the cloned graph.`.

Can any one help me understand, why const the var declaration matters here ? For this coding, `var`, `let`, `const` can pass, however, `var` says to be global, `const` and `let` seems like to be block level right ?  Thanks.

However, when use `d` and `c` blow, we can get the same output as object.

```
    d = new Node(node.val)
    console.log(d)
    
    const c = new Node(node.val)
    console.log(c)
```

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/#:~:text=var%20declarations%20are%20globally%20scoped%20or%20function%20scoped%20while%20let,be%20updated%20nor%20re%2Ddeclared. Refer this

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. But if we do not use the declaration, we assume the variable as the global right ? for this question, I tested the const, var and let , all can pass the question!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) - Your issue is with the closure. Without using var, const, let the variable is used _for each iteration_ of the recursion.

Comment: There, `scope` means `accessible`, not object life-cycle. And yes - it will override the global variable if you don't use var/let/const in front of variable declaration.

Comment: In many contexts, it doesn't matter a whether you use *const*, *let* or *var*. Both *const* and *let* are block scoped, but that doesn't stop them being use for globals.

Comment: I much prefer *let* for objects as *const* is not semantic to use for something that can be modified, i.e. isn't a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `root` has been declare as global variable and be changed in every recursive loop, in this line:
`root.neighbors.push(recursion(node.neighbors[i]));`
`root` will not be the current node that in current loop, but the last reference it has been assigned to.

Let demonstrate it by an simple graph:

```js
const oldGraph = [{
  val: 1,
  neighbors: [{
    val: 2
  }, {
    val: 3
  }]
}];
```

So run `cloneGraph(oldGraph[0])`, after value 2 done return after check `!node.neighbors`, recursion back to the line `root.neighbors.push(recursion(node.neighbors[i]));`. Now `root` is the node 2 because it has been assigned to new node val 2 in the second recursion, not the root as node 1 you expected.

The variable declaration with `var`, `let`, `const` helps in this case, because they keep the `root` scope inside current recursion, each iteration will create a new root, not changed any other references.

Test here:

```js
function Node(node) {
  this.val = node.val;
  this.neighbors = [];
}

var cloneGraph = function(node) {
    
    visited = {};
    return recursion(node);
    
    function recursion(node){
        
        if (!node) return null;
        if (visited[node.val]) return visited[node.val];
        
        // clone node and clone edge
        // **I forgot the let, var, const variable declaration here**
        let root = new Node(node);
        visited[root.val] = root;
        
        if (!node.neighbors) return root;
        for (let i = 0; i < node.neighbors.length; i++) {
            root.neighbors.push(recursion(node.neighbors[i]));
        }
        return root;
    }
};

oldGraph = [{
  val: 1,
  neighbors: [{
    val: 2
  }, {
    val: 3
  }]
}];

console.log(cloneGraph(oldGraph[0]));
```